# tofloat function in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, image-processing

Why **tofloat** function is not working in MATLAB 2010? is it omitted or just replaced with something else? 
This function converts  an  image  of  class  logical,  uint8,  uint16,  or  int16  to  class  single, applying the appropriate scale factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think **tofloat** was ever a part of offical matlab. It is a support function used by the [imageprocessingplace](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/) books/exercises. You can find the code for **tofloat** [here](https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ifcb-web/repository/revisions/290/entry/trunk/dipum_toolbox_2.0.1/tofloat.m).

Comment: could you explain what it is and when it is used? tofloat function